# 英語が残っている: Your bounty on question "〜" is completed

Tags: バグ, 翻訳, 英語

「お礼」が切れたときの通知メッセージが未翻訳なのを発見しました。

以下、スクリーンショットです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

例えばこんな感じですかね...。

> 質問「...」に提供したお礼が終了しました。お礼を贈る回答を24時間以内に選んでください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Transifex: https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/64880389?key=07e8dd7537b8f75ae439c00477f0c09b

Comment: 翻訳を更新しました。次回のビルドで適用されます。